# Customize select dropdown list CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to style the dropdown list of a  element. I know how to customize the dropdown container and the arrow, but I want to be able to customize the background of the dropdown list and the color of the  elements.

Comment: Do not hesitate to show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You'd simply target `option` for each of the option elements. Note that you'll also have to target `select` in order to style the **default** selected `<option>`.

Considering `option` is a child of `select`, it will inherit the rules, and as such, you can simply target `select`.

Then you're just looking for the **[`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)** and **[`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)** CSS properties.

```css
select {
  background: red;
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello! This only styles the dropdown container. I want to style the dropdown list (when you click the arrow).

Comment: The above styles both the dropdown container (the `<select>`) and the list (the `<option>` elements). I've confirmed this to be the case in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. If it is not working for you, please let me know which **browser** you are using. It's also possible that specificity is an issue. It would be helpful if you updated your question to show your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if applying this snippet does not work for you.